# Maximise $v + r \omega$ in $E = \frac{1}{2}m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 $

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, velocity

I'm working out the maximum 'speed' that an object can cut a light gate, but the object can both rotate and move linearly.

The maximum speed measured by the light gate can be approximated as $k = r\omega + v$, with $\omega r$ being the angular velocity of the bar.
The total energy in the system limits the angular and linear velocity of the bar, $E = \frac{1}{2}m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 $.

Combining both equations leads to $0 = mk^2 - 2 m r \omega k + ((I + mr^2 )\omega^2 - 2E)$ because:

$$ 2E = mv^2 + I \omega^2$$
$$ 0 = m(k-r\omega)^2 + I \omega^2 - 2E$$

which can be simplified by discriminant rule to find that 
$$k = \frac{\sqrt{m((I+m)\omega^2 - 2E)}}{m r\omega}$$

This is confusing to me because if you increase the energy in the system, $((I + mr^2)\omega^2 - 2E)$ decreases, decreasing $k$. Any help surrounding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what the discriminant rule is, but when I solve for $k$ directly I get $k = r\omega + \sqrt{\frac{2E - I\omega^2}{m}}$

Comment: I'm confused what you think you're doing. You derive a quadratic equation for $k$ but don't solve it correctly. You are trying to maximise $k$ but never differentiate. Have you heard of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @d_b If you put that in a comment I'll mark the answer as solved.

Comment: @jacob1729 I'm a highschool student whose just using the tools accessible to me. I likened it too much to a maths problem about adjusting the coeffecients of a line for the line to become a tangent to a circle.

Comment: @Krish I didn't mean that to sound condescending. I am genuinely confused where you get the equation for $k$ from. The mention of disciminants in particular is interesting. Lagrange multipliers aren't that hard and do I think make the algebra easier to organise in this case - you might want to take this as an opportunity to learn about them.

Comment: @jacob1729 The discriminant rule effectively comes from the quadratic formula with the \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}. For real solutions of x in any quadratic b^2 >= 4ac (consider x^2 + 1 = 0). Now if you have a discriminant equal to zero, it implies that there is only one solution to x. In context to with my 'line and tangent' thinking it corresponds with the line being a tangent, and b^2 > 4ac occurs when the line passes through the circle twice creating two roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the discriminant rule is (I guess you mean the quadratic formula), but from
\begin{align}
2E = m\left(k - r\omega\right)^2 + I \omega^2
\end{align}
we can solve for $k$ directly:
\begin{align}
\left(k - r\omega\right)^2 = \frac{2E - I \omega^2}{m}\\
\rightarrow k = r\omega + \sqrt{\frac{2E - I \omega^2}{m}} 
\end{align}
No quadratic formula needed.